# Kappa Statistic Extremely Large/Sparse matrix

Tags: r

I have a large sparseMatrix (mat):

```
138493 x 17694 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix", with 10000132 entries
```

I want to investigate Inter-rating agreement using kappa statistics but when I run Fleiss:

```
kappam.fleiss(mat)
```

I am shown the following error

```
Error in asMethod(object) : 
  Cholmod error 'problem too large' at file ../Core/cholmod_dense.c, line 105
```

Is this due to my matrix being too large?

Is there any other methods I can use to calculate kappa statistics for IRR on a matrix this large?

Comment: Can you supply some details as to the contents and format of this matrix? What do the rows, columns, and cell entries represent?

Comment: Each row corresponds to a movie, each column is a user and the cells are the ratings (0-5 by 0.5 increments) that a user gave to a movie.

Comment: So most of the sparseness, which here is > 99.59% of your matrix, comes from users not having rated a movie, rather than zeros?

Comment: Yes, the values are empty rather than 0.

Answer (score 3):

The best answer that I can offer is that this is **not really possible due to the extreme sparsity** in your matrix.  The problem: With 10,000,132 entries for a 138,493 * 17694 = 2,450,495,142 cell matrix, you have mostly (99.59%) missing values.  The `irr` package allows for these but here you are placing some extreme demands on the system, by asking it to compare ratings for users whose films do not overlap.

This is compounded by the problem that the methods in the `irr` package a) require dense matrixes as input, and b) (at least in `kripp.alpha()` loop over columns making them very slow.

Here is an illustration constructing a matrix similar in nature to yours (but with no pattern - in reality your situation will be better because viewers tend to rate similar sets of movies).

Note that I used **Krippendorff's alpha** here, since it allows for ordinal or interval ratings (as your data suggests), and normally handles missing data fine.

```
require(Matrix)
require(irr)
seed <- 100
(sparseness <- 1 - 10000132 / (138493 * 17694))
## [1] 0.9959191
138493 / 17694 # multiple of movies to users
## [1] 7.827117
# nraters <- 17694
# nusers <- 138493
nmovies <- 100
nusers <- 783
raterMatrix <- 
    Matrix(sample(c(NA, seq(0, 5, by = .5)), nmovies * nusers, replace = TRUE,
                  prob = c(sparseness, rep((1-sparseness)/11, 11))),
           nrow = nmovies, ncol = nusers)
kripp.alpha(t(as.matrix(raterMatrix)), method = "interval")
## Krippendorff's alpha
##
## Subjects = 100 
##   Raters = 783 
##    alpha = -0.0237
```

This worked for that size matrix, but fails if I increase it 100x (10x on each dimension), keeping the same proportions as in your reported dataset, then it fails to produce an answer after even 30 minutes, so I killed the process.

**What to conclude:** You are not really asking the right question of this data.  It's not an issue of how many users agreed, but probably what sort of dimensions exist in this data in terms of clusters of viewing and clusters of preferences.  You probably want to use association rules or some dimensional reduction methods that don't balk at the sparsity in your dataset.